# Trouble getting aggregate sum function to correctly count elements

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My job is parsing http log requests, and the very last statement is looking for a field called `controller_type` to see if it is `like` certain criteria, and then checking to see if it `isNotNull`.  If that is the case, it assigns it a value of 1, otherwise 0, and then creates a sum column of those 1's and zeros.  Problem is, my job is counting them if they match the `controller_type` criteria, and not really paying attention to the `isNotNull` portion.  Do I have a logic or syntax error, or am I doing something incorrectly in how I have this expression structured?

```
df = df.groupby(
            fn.trunc(df['request_timestamp'], 'mon').alias(
                'request_timestamp'),
            df['account_id'],
            df['account_guid'],
            df['cluster_id'],
            df['shard_id'],
            df['unique_id'],
            df['context_id'],
            df['controller_type'],
            df['controller_context_id'],
            df['concat_user_id'],
            df['user_id']) \
            .agg(
            fn.count(df['account_id']).alias('num_page_views'),
            fn.sum(
                fn.when(
                    ((df['controller_type'].like('pages%')) &
                    (df['controller_context_id'].isNotNull())),
                    fn.lit(1))
                    .otherwise(fn.lit(0))
            ).alias('num_page_views_pages'),
            fn.sum(
                fn.when(
                    ((df['controller_type'].like('files%')) &
                    (df['controller_context_id'].isNotNull())),
                    fn.lit(1))
                    .otherwise(fn.lit(0))
            ).alias('num_page_views_files'),
            fn.sum(
                fn.when(
                    ((df['controller_type'].like('modules%')) &
                    (df['controller_context_id'].isNotNull())),
                    fn.lit(1))
                    .otherwise(fn.lit(0))
            ).alias('num_page_views_modules'),
            fn.sum(
                fn.when(
                    ((df['controller_type'].like('assignments%')) &
                    (df['controller_context_id'].isNotNull())),
                    fn.lit(1))
                    .otherwise(fn.lit(0))
            ).alias('num_page_views_assignments'),
            fn.sum(
                fn.when(
                    ((df['controller_type'].like('quizzes%')) &
                    (df['controller_context_id'].isNotNull())),
                    fn.lit(1))
                    .otherwise(fn.lit(0))
            ).alias('num_page_views_quizzes'),
            fn.sum(
                fn.when(
                    ((df['controller_type'].like('discussion_topics%')) &
                    (df['controller_context_id'].isNotNull())),
                    fn.lit(1))
                    .otherwise(fn.lit(0))
            ).alias('num_page_views_discussion_topics'),
            fn.sum(
                fn.when(
                    ((df['controller_type'].like('outcome%')) &
                    (df['controller_context_id'].isNotNull())),
                    fn.lit(1))
                    .otherwise(fn.lit(0))
            ).alias('num_page_views_outcomes'),
            fn.countDistinct(df['user_id']).alias('num_distinct_user_logins'),
            fn.countDistinct(df['session_id']).alias('num_sessions')
        )
```

Here would be the equivalent `SQL` statement:

```
SELECT
            TRUNC(request_timestamp, 'month') AS request_timestamp,
            account_id,
            account_guid,
            cluster_id,
            shard_id,
            unique_id,
            context_id,
            controller_type,
            controller_context_id,
            concat_user_id,
            user_id,
            COUNT(account_id) AS num_page_views,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'pages%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_pages,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'files%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_files,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'modules%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_modules,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'assignments%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_assignments,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'quizzes%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_quizzes,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'discussion_topics%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_discussion_topics,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'outcome%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_outcomes,
            COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) AS num_sessions
        FROM requests
        GROUP BY
          TRUNC(request_timestamp, 'month'),
          account_id,
          account_guid,
          cluster_id,
          shard_id,
          unique_id,
          context_id,
          context_id,
          controller_type,
          controller_context_id,
          concat_user_id,
          user_id
```

I'm thinking that I'm missing something, because trying a small toy problem, it doesn't seem to be aggregating correctly:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('something', 'null', 'something'), ('null', 'something', 'something'), ('something', 'something', 'something')], ['a', 'b', 'c'])

df.groupby(df.a, df.b, df.c).agg(sum(when(df.a.isNotNull(), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)).alias('sum_col'))).show()
```

My result was:

```
+---------+---------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
|        a|        b|        c|sum(CASE WHEN isnotnull(a) THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS sum_col#3)|
+---------+---------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
|something|something|something|                                                     1|
|something|     null|something|                                                     1|
|     null|something|something|                                                     1|
+---------+---------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The main missing part is that `'null' IS NOT NULL`. You should use `None` on Python side.

Comment: @zero323 so I shouldn't ever use `.isNotNull/isNull`?  Or would you mind clarifying where to use `None`?

Comment: And you simplify the rest with https://gist.github.com/zero323/152fb4fb5b23025bfab4f89ca7bf51a2

Comment: Python `None` is converted to SQL `NULL`. String `null` is just a string like any other.

Comment: So I could do something like `df.column not  None`?

Comment: No you cannot. You still have to use `isNull`. `not None` will be always true because it checks object identity.

Comment: I apologize, I'm not understanding where in my script I could use `None`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116120/discussion-between-flybonzai-and-zero323).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work on a toy data because string "null" `IS NOT NULL` so it cannot be filtered out. If you want to check if field contains `"null"` use equality `==`. Lets illustrate that with a simple example

```py
df = sc.parallelize([
    (1, "null", ),
    (2, None, ), 
    (3, "foo", )
]).toDF(["id", "x"])


df.select("*",
    fn.col("x").isNull(),    # check if value IS NULL  - OK
    fn.col("x") == "null",   # check if value = 'null' - not valid here 
    fn.col("x") == None      # check if value = NULL   - WRONG - always NULL!
    ## fn.col("x") is None   # Check if column is None - WRONG!
).show()

## +---+----+---------+----------+----------+
## | id|   x|isnull(x)|(x = null)|(x = null)|
## +---+----+---------+----------+----------+
## |  1|null|    false|      true|      null|   # string = "null" but is NOT NULL
## |  2|null|     true|      null|      null|   # NULL IS NULL, but != 'null'
## |  3| foo|    false|     false|      null|   # not null
## +---+----+---------+----------+----------+
```

Moreover you can easily simplify all the conditions to something like this:

```py
checks = [
    ('pages%', 'num_page_views_assignments'),
    ('quizzes%', 'num_page_views_quizzes'),
    ...
]

def count_like(pattern, label):
   cond = (
       fn.col('controller_type').like(pattern) &
       fn.col('controller_context_id').isNotNull()
   )

   # Count will count only NOT NULL. We can omit otherwise
   # and choose arbitrary value
   return fn.count(fn.when(cond, 1).alias(label))

(df
    .groupBy(...)
    .agg(*[count_like(p, l) for p, l in checks]))
```